# powershell script update to check percent diskspace & exit jenkins stage depending on that

Tags: powershell, jenkins-pipeline

I would check percent diskspace & exit jenkins stage depending on that

I think I can work around something like :

```
PS C:\Users\Administrator> Get-WmiObject win32_logicaldisk | select name,freespace,size,@{Name='%';Expression={($_.freespace/ $_.size)*100}}                                                                       

name    freespace         size                %
----    ---------         ----                -
C:    15582232576  79473668096 19.6067866871043
D:
E:
F:   247559806976 449998483456 55.0134758399038


PS C:\Users\Administrator>
```

my current Jenkins groovy file steps looks like :

```
            stage ('test') {
                agent {
                    node {
                        label "test"
                        customWorkspace "F:\\app"
                    }
                }
                steps
                {
                    script
                    {
                        bat """
                            f:
                            cd \\app
                            python somescript.py
                            python otherscript.py
                            Powershell("Get-wmiObject -Class win32_logicaldisk")
                        """
                }
            }
```

Question is in few points :

- how to select only F: ?
- how to round % to integer ?
- how to compare it to a fixed value (let's say 80%) ?
- how to exit Jenkins step as "OK" whatever status is if this value isn't exceeded ? (and "KO" exle)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To round and limit to F plus check if over 80% free and if *under* 80% free exit with 1 which should drive Jenkins to consider the step as failed :

```
$Full=Get-WmiObject win32_logicaldisk | 
   select name,freespace,size,
          @{Name='%';Expression={[math]::Round(($_.freespace/ $_.size)*100)}},
          @{Name='Full';Expression={[math]::Round(($_.freespace/ $_.size)*100) -lt 80}} | 
   where name -eq "F:" | 
     select -Unique Full ;
if ($Full.Full -eq $True) { $host.SetShouldExit(1); } else { $host.SetShouldExit(0); }
```

To manually test it (here with a F: partition with 24% free space) :

```
PROMPT>powershell -command "$Full=Get-WmiObject win32_logicaldisk | select name,freespace,size,@{Name='%';Expression={[math]::Round(($_.freespace/ $_.size)*100)}},@{Name='Full';Expression={[math]::Round(($_.freespace/ $_.size)*100) -lt 80}} | where name -eq "F:" | select -Unique Full ;  if ($Full.Full -eq $True) { $host.SetShouldExit(1); } else { $host.SetShouldExit(0); }"

PROMPT>echo %ERRORLEVEL%
1
```

And when the threshold is set to 20% free space:

```
PROMPT>powershell -command "$Full=Get-WmiObject win32_logicaldisk | select name,freespace,size,@{Name='%';Expression={[math]::Round(($_.freespace/ $_.size)*100)}},@{Name='Full';Expression={[math]::Round(($_.freespace/ $_.size)*100) -lt 20}} | where name -eq "F:" | select -Unique Full ;  if ($Full.Full -eq $True) { $host.SetShouldExit(1); } else { $host.SetShouldExit(0); }"

PROMPT>echo %ERRORLEVEL%
0
```

Command in your groovy file should embed the whole line and look like :

```
 Powershell("$Full=Get-WmiObject win32_logicaldisk | select name,freespace,size,@{Name='%';Expression={[math]::Round(($_.freespace/ $_.size)*100)}},@{Name='Full';Expression={[math]::Round(($_.freespace/ $_.size)*100) -lt 80}} | where name -eq "F:" | select -Unique Full ;  if ($Full.Full -eq $True) { $host.SetShouldExit(1); } else { $host.SetShouldExit(0); }")
```

In case you want to script an action directly in the jenkins node :

```
    def status = Powershell(returnStatus: true, script: "$Full=Get-WmiObject win32_logicaldisk | select name,freespace,size,@{Name='%';Expression={[math]::Round(($_.freespace/ $_.size)*100)}},@{Name='Full';Expression={[math]::Round(($_.freespace/ $_.size)*100) -lt 80}} | where name -eq "F:" | select -Unique Full ;  if ($Full.Full -eq $True) { $host.SetShouldExit(1); } else { $host.SetShouldExit(0); }")
    if (status == 0) {
        // F: has enough space
    } else {
        // F: is Full
    }
```